# Sequence unifomly bounded

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, sequences-and-series

Let $f(\lambda,z)$ be a  continuous function on $\Bbb R^2$ such that

I) For $n\in\Bbb N$ and  $x\in\Bbb R^*_+$ we have : $f(n,x)=\cos(nx)+ x O\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)$ as $n\to\infty$  and $x\in[n^{-1}\epsilon,\omega]$.

II) $\forall n\in\Bbb N : f(n,x)\sim \dfrac{e^{-x}}{n+1}$ as $x\to\infty$.

**My question**: can we say that $f(n,x)$ is unifomly bounded on $\Bbb N\times\Bbb R^*_+$?

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions.

My attempt: There are 3 cases:

1. by hypothesis II,  $\exists\omega>0$ such that :  $\forall n\in\Bbb N$ and  $\forall x>\omega$ we have:
   $|f(n,x)|\leq C$
   for some constant $C$.
2. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $0<x\leq\omega$, by hypothesis I, $\exists n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $$|f(n,x)|\leq |f(n,x)-\cos(nx)|+|\cos(nx)|\leq C'$$ for all $n\geq n_0$ and for all $x\in[n^{-1}_0\epsilon,\omega]$.
3. for all $n\leq n_0$ and for all $x\in \big[0, n^{-1}_0\epsilon\big]$ we have $|f(n,x)|\leq C_1$ for some constant $C_1$ because $f$ is continuous on $[0,n_0]\times\big[0, n^{-1}_0\epsilon\big]$.

is it correct?

Comment: When you say “uniformly bounded”, what do you mean precisely?

Comment: uniformly bounded means $\forall(n,x)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{R}_+:\big|f(n,x)\big|\leq C$ with $C$ is a Constant

Comment: @ Jack L,  could you see my proof